# Input hides jquery drop down menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, input, overlapping

Here is the image of a local site
 [image]

How can I make it so the drop down menu hides the input instead?

Comment: `position: absolute;` and `z-index` will fix that problem for you.

Comment: Ah of course, that seems so obvious now. Thanks! :)